# PHP text/plain result + Character set

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have implemented a PHP script which results to a string.
I have specified the content type as text/plain.

I call my PHP script via an AJAX request.
I use a jQuery function to perform the AJAX request.
Then I retrieve the result string and I insert it into the DOM.
The content-type of my calling HTML page is iso-8859-1.

But the result string is not correctly displayed in my calling HTML page.
Letters e with acute accent are replaced with special characters.

Does anyone know which character set is implicitly used to encode the string resulting from my PHP script ?
If the character set used is different from iso-8859-1 then how can I reencode the result string with the iso-8859-1 character set ?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are UTF-8 by default.

Your Ajax resource should be emitting UTF-8 data. The browser should automatically convert the result to the page's local character set, in your case ISO-8859-1.

If your Ajax resource is outputting ISO-8859-1 data, use something like

```
$data = iconv($data, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

to enforce UTF-8 on it. (Alternatively, use `utf8_encode()` which does the same thing.)

Comment: Are you sure, that the browser automatically converts from UTF-8 (Ajax result) to ISO-8859-1 (HTML page)? Recently i changed all my HTML pages to the UTF-8 format, because the browser _didn't_ do this, and i wanted to avoid such encoding problems (all is UTF-8 now).

Comment: @Martin AFAIK it *should* automatically convert it if the page's encoding is clearly defined, but I can't find an authoritative source defining this right now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, in your PHP script :

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
```